# Run all Ui Tests from one general class

Tags: android, android-studio, android-testing, android-espresso

I write UI-tests on Espresso library for my custom components. I have separate classes, that extends `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MyActivityDebug>`, for every component, for example: `CheckBoxTest`, `EditTextTest`, `SelectorText`... Now i run tests separately too. Help me, how can i run all tests one time from one place for all classes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define a `Suite`

```
/**
 * Runs all unit tests.
 */
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({MyTest1.class , MyTest2.class, MyTest3.class})
public class InstrumentationTestSuite {}
```

Then in AndroidStudio you can run with gradle or setting a new configuration like:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
public class AllGuiTestsTablet extends TestCase {

 public static TestSuite suite() {
 TestSuite t = new TestSuite("YourAwesomeTests");

 t.addTestSuite(CheckBoxTest.class);
 t.addTestSuite(EditTextTest.class);
 return t;
    }
}
```

Just add all your tests to a testSuite and you should be fine